# Is it fair to ask a team to start using CoffeeScript?

Tags: team

I started my new job as a JS developer in November and starting implementing Backbone pretty soon after. This was a big enough learning curve for the team (me included), however I'm thinking about looking at CoffeeScript, which I'm guessing would require everyone on the team to know it? Is that too big of an ask, just to make me slightly more productive?

Comment: Well, what did the other people on your team say?

Comment: @user16764 "I'm thinking about looking at CoffeeScript" - it's all hypothetical at the moment!

Comment: Why does taking the productivity hit associated with changing frameworks have an acceptable cost within your organization? Do you have to give a business, dollars and cents, reason for this change, especially since it would be the second one within a year?

Comment: Why? What is it about CoffeeScript, that you think will make you or your team more productive?

Comment: No, cruel and unusual punishment is illegal.

Comment: I dislike being forced to write JS in somebody else's slightly reinvented paradigm. I'm an expert JS developer turned off by that choice. I might have to suck it up and deal to get the work I want but if I have a choice I'll pick the shop without CoffeeScript which wouldn't bother me one lick if all it did was pull semis, parens and curlies out. Then we could both work with or without it on the same team without any real variation in the handwritten design of it when "compiled." So there's one thing for a team to consider. Who is that choice going to alienate from your hiring pool?

Answer (score 10):

Introducing new skills and technologies should be a team decision. Your team needs to maintain your code if you are off sick, leave, or get hit by a bus. What does your team say? I have lost count of the number of projects that have been expensively damage to the point of needing a rewrite by some maverick introducing his favourite technology that no-one else understands, so make sure you are backed by consensus.

Comment: Hm, introducing CoffeeScript to a web development team isn't exactly the same as introducing any other technology. A web development team is (or at least should be) already familiar with the compiled output of CoffeeScript.

Comment: @YannisRizos They may be familiar with the compiled output of CoffeeScript, but that's not the same as familiarity with CoffeeScript itself, which has it's own syntax and conventions that have to be learned in order to maintain code written in it. I'd say it would fall squarely in the "new technology" category.

Comment: Agree with @YannisRizos at this point. It is easy to read (and maintain) code that is an output of CoffeeScript re-compilation, so it is not the same answer as if we were discussing the introduction of python/java/c# etc...

Comment: @YannisRizos "The compiled output of CoffeeScript" is not what you're asking your fellow developers to maintain. It's the source CoffeeScript.

Comment: @Tim Hm? Why? Worst case scenario (you get hit by a bus), your team just compiles your scripts, and then replaces them with the JS output. Simple as that, and all they have to maintain from now on is vanilla JS. There will be a small learning curve, but we are talking days, not weeks or months.

Comment: I read the question as asking if it's fair to ask the team to use CoffeeScript, not if it's fair to share the output of CoffeeScript instead of writing the javascript directly.

Comment: @YannisRizos So I'm going to add some BananaScript to the project, and Joe, the new guy, is going to use SomeMadeUpScript because he saw it once and it looked cool. Neither of us tell anyone, but it's fine because they are even easier to learn than CoffeeScript, so there will only be a small learning curve. ;-) Where do you draw the line?

Comment: @Tim I don't think you got my point, no one actually needs to learn CoffeeScript. CoffeeScript compiles to plain old vanilla JS, a technology that the team is _already_ familiar with (assuming they are a web development team, of course). If the team member that introduced CoffeeScript disappears, the team is left with plain old vanilla JS, not with an unfamiliar technology. They can of course learn CoffeeScript if they want, but they _don't_ have to.

Comment: @EricKing The OP is unfamiliar with CoffeeScript and he incorrectly assumes that introducing CoffeeScript to the team means that they'll have to use it ("I'm guessing would require everyone on the team to know it?"). Obviously it would be preferable if the team picked up on CoffeeScript eventually, but it's not a requirement. It's not a new language, it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @YannisRizos I understand what you're saying... It's like using Resharper to help write .NET code faster/better. Just because one person uses it doesn't mean everyone has to. But still, the answer is exactly the same. Before going forward with using CoffeeScript-generated javascript (or Resharper-refactored code), _ask the team how they feel about it_. They may not care one way or the other, or there may be serious misgivings. There's no way to know without bringing it up.

Comment: @EricKing No argument there. All I'm saying is that it's not as big a deal as, for example, asking a team to switch from Java to Python.

Comment: @YannisRizos We're on the same page with that one. :-)

Comment: There's a difference between JS written for legibility and compiled coffeeScript. Being somebody who knows a lot about JS, I don't like being yoked with a tool that doesn't give me complete access to JS's design features. And no, I really don't give a flying !@#$ what Crockford's opinion is on the features that CS supposedly "fixes." And why does everybody keep saying it's so much like JS it doesn't matter but that it improves their productivity in the same breath? Syntax sugar is a ridiculous reason to transpile a language over JS.

Answer (score 1):

When working with good teams it is totally fair to introduce technologies to the team as a whole with a bit of a "Lunch and Learn" or some other format where you can go over the good and bad. Then one must let the team decide if this is a proper thing to use or not. It never works well to force a team to adopt a technology, doubly so when they are not ready for it.

If you are the team lead, or senior developer, or in any kind of leadership role, this is much more important. It can change how your team views your leadership abilities. If you introduce CoffeeScript as something that might be very useful, and demonstrate why and you can answer any questions they have and most importantly be ready to mentor and work with them then go for it.

Worst thing you can do is say, "Here is CoffeeScript. We are going to use it. It is very powerful and it will make your life easier here." and then not explain to them why, or how or even let them take the time to come to that conclusion themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about how it is done, and what your team is like.

A really smart technical team embraces change and doesn't care who introduces a piece of new technology so long as it helps of course.

The flip side is that is very often not the case.

Being the new guy can work against you ("who does this guy think he is?").

Not being a "lead" can work against you ("he can't tell us what to do!").

Comment: "so long as it helps of course" is the key here. Especially as we are talking about a language switch, from a high-level language to another high-level language. It will be hard to prove CoffeeScript would help.

Answer (score 1):

How will introducing Coffeescript save/earn your employer money? If you can come up with a realistic answer to that then suggest it to your team. Your CV skills do not appear on the company balance sheet.

Answer (score 0):

For introducing a new technology, you will want to get some buy-in.  It should help the entire team in its implementation.  Shoving it down people's throats will cause them to keep it from being successful.

> Is that too big of an ask, just to make me slightly more productive?

So you become slightly more productive, what are the benefits for the other members?  Will they become more productive?  Will the quality of the product that they are producing be better?

Do you have buy-in for implementing this from your customers/management?  Will they accept a slow down in productivity while the team learns a new technology?  What are the benefits for them?  If you just implemented Backbone, they might not be as patient for another change.